# How to create application-wide Scala functions which perform web service calls in Play 2.4?

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework

I want to create a `LinkedinApi` class, containing functions which execute web service requests to Linkedin servers. These functions need to be accessible from anywhere in the Play app code. The easiest way I've written such API classes in the past, was to have them declared as an `object`. Then  `LinkedinApi.myPublicFunction()` is available from anywhere.

The problem is that I don't see how I can declare my `LinkedinApi` class as an `object`. It would use Play 2.4's web services, and this is done by adding `@Inject()(ws: WSClient)` to the class declaration. Something like `object LinkedinApi @Inject()(ws: WSClient) extends Controller`.

The problem is that the line above doesn't compile. It seems that `@Inject` can only be used with `class` declarations, not with `object`.

So how can I create application-wide API functions which perform web service calls?

Comment: Why don't you create LinkedinApi as a singleton service and inject it wherever you want?

Comment: @nyavro That could very well be the solution. I've never used singletons yet, or injected them for that matter. Would you like to detail how to do so in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should define your LinkedinApi as a service and inject it where needed:

```
@Singleton
class LinkedinApi @Inject()(ws: WSClient) {
   //...
   //linkedin stuff
   //...
}
```

and inject as:

```
@Singleton
class SomeController @Inject()(linkedinApi:LinkedinApi) {
    //...
}
```